# Auto deleting an object based on some conditions in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is there anyway to delete an object based on some conditions? For example, if `cascade:delete-orphan` is indicated in a relationship, it will delete the child when the parent is deleted. What I am looking for is to delete an object when some condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you're looking for [query.delete()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html?highlight=query.delete#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete) ?

```
session.query(MyClass).filter_by(some_col='fred').delete(synchronize_session=False)
```